# How to show and hide navigationBar?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, hidden

I have two UITableViewController, and in each of them NavigationBar is visible; then I have a simple UIViewController. So I'd like to make NavigationBar invisible only in the third view. I tried

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

but this make navigationBar invisibile in every view, after I leave the third one.

I also tried

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This is my application scheme: only in "DettaglioController" I'd like to make navigationBar invisible.

[image]

Any ideas to solve?

Comment: ok then you can use my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just one line of code....

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

In the ViewControllers viewWillAppear you can hide the NavigationBar like this, and in its viewWillDisappear you can show it back again

Comment: You can choose where to put it... try out the viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, and viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear until you have it showing and hiding the way you want